# .NET Core Web API HttpContext.User.Claims and HttpContext.User.Identity are always null in Controllers

Tags: c#, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-identity

I am using an ASP.NET Core Web API for the back-end and using JWT token in httpClient's header of a Blazor WASM client (I don't store JWT tokens in a cookie).

The problem is that although the user is logged in and the authentication and authorization works with no problems, but in every controller (inherited from `ControllerBase`) always:

- `HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is false
- `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name` is null
- `HttpContext.User.Claims` is null

But the request has the JWT token (`Request.Headers["Authorization"][0]` is equal to `Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1...`) and `[Authorize]` attribute works correctly.

This is how my startup.cs looks like:

```
services.AddIdentity()
            
services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationPolicyProvider, AuthorizeExPolicyProvider>();

services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                              options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
                        Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["jwt:key"])),
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
                });

services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
            });
```

And I also called the middleware in the right order :

```
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
```

Comment: Could you show us the attributes you have added to your controller's?

Comment: @Nisd only HttpGet in this case. but there are other method with Authorize attribute too

Comment: @Nisd your comment was helpful. actually I was testing it with a method that does not had any Authorize attribute therefor the answer is to use Authorize Attribute . Feel free to add it as an answer. Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`HttpContext.User` is only set when you have authentication for the method enabled.

You can enable it by setting `[Authorize]` on your controller or action, or configure a global filter so all requests are authorized by default.