# Get claims from jwt token into context.User.Claims

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, jwt, claims-based-identity

I'm trying to get claims from the JWT token into `context.User.Claims` in my ASP.NET Core 5 Web API. I'm using Azure and have registered an app in Azure AD in our tenant.

The code is in an `Authorization` handler.

When I read the JWT token (`context.Request.Headers["Authorization"]`) using `JwtSecurityTokenHandler`, I can get all claims, but my `context.User.Claims` is still empty.

The `aud` and `iss` values show up as:

```
[aud, https://graph.microsoft.com]
[iss, https://sts.windows.net/[tenant-id]/]
```

This is my `Startup.ConfigureServices()` method:

```
services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
{
    sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(option =>
{
    option.Audience = audience;
    option.Authority = authority; 
    option.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromHours(1), 
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidIssuer = authority,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidAudience = audience
    };
});
```

What am I supposed to put in `audience` and `authority`? I have tested the values I got from the JWT token (above).

I have also tried with:

- authority (issuer): `https://login.microsoftonline.com/[tenant-id]/v2.0`
- audience: `app://[client-id]`

and all combinations. Same result

Answer (score 0):

Initially, try to decode the token using [**jwt.ms**](https://jwt.ms/) and check what claims the token contains.

- For **Audience** parameter, you can use the **Application ID URI** (api://your_app_id) or **scope** ([https://graph.microsoft.com](https://graph.microsoft.com/)).
- For **Authority** parameter, you can use the address of the token-issuing authentication server. Please note that, issuer value differs depending on the [type of token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840510/validating-the-issuer-token-has-issuer-https-login-microsoftonline-com-xv2-0?rq=1)  you are generating (v1.0/v2.0).
- For v1.0 token -> `https://sts.windows.net< Azure AD Tenant GUID>/`
- For v2.0 token -> `https://login.microsoftonline.com<Azure AD Tenant GUID>/v2.0`

To confirm and know more about the parameters, refer to the [**blog**](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/jwt-validation-and-authorization-in-asp-net-core/#jwt-authentication) by **Jeffrey Fritz**.

> To receive the claims, make sure to add **[Authorize] attribute** with *HTTP
> context header.*

Please check whether you included **`app.UseAuthorization`** or not.

Make sure to call the middleware in the order like below from this [**MS Doc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#configure-identity-services-1):

```cs
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

If the issue persists, then try to modify the **`Startup.cs -> ConfigureServices()`** method as mentioned in this [**blog**](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2021/Mar/09/Role-based-JWT-Tokens-in-ASPNET-Core#setting-up-jwt-authentication-and-authorization).

You can **refer** to the links below that can give you some pointers to resolve the issue:

[identityserver4 - User.Claims is empty ASP.NET 5.0 - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64842625/user-claims-is-empty-after-upgrading-from-asp-net-core-3-1-to-asp-net-5-0)

[.NET Core Web API HttpContext.User.Claimsare always null - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71107247/net-core-web-api-httpcontext-user-claims-and-httpcontext-user-identity-are-alwa)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are getting the wrong type of JWT, with a `nonce` field in the JWT header, that does not validate properly in your own APIs. To fix this there is an `Expose an API scope` option.

There are some visual details about this from step 3 of my [blog post](https://authguidance.com/2017/12/01/azure-ad-spa-code-sample/) from a few years back. You can then configure the issuer and audience as in my [API code example config](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.azure/blob/master/api/api.config.json).